# how can i allow wifi for specific user

Tags: networking

I have setup an Ubuntu server with multiple user for remote access. The public internet access is thru wifi. I need to block the public internet access for all user except two users, root and admin

Now I could had used the following command
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner user_you_want_to_block -j REJEC
This will block all the outgoing traffic for the user which I cannot do, I need allow all the user to use intranet which is thru the eth0

How should i do this

Nisheeth

Answer (score 0):

Could try to shut the card off with a logon script. Something like,

`#!/bin/bash
sudo iwconfig wlan0 down`

This would leave the eth0 card up and running for your intranet use.

Comment: This will shutdown the wlan0 for all users.I want to allow wifi for certain users and block for other users

Comment: Add it to the INDIVIDUAL USER'S logon scripts. That way it'll only take effect if the user has this script set in their startup apps preferences. You could always do the opposite too (ie. shut the card off system wide and then reenable for root and admin with 'iwconfig wlan0 up' at login) http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login